# how to make lines in html & css

Tags: html, css

I want to make design only all lines like in this image. Please See image. Thanks for your time.
[image: image here]

Comment: SO is not a code factory where you just can ask for some code. Maybe you can refer to https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp as a jump start

Answer (score 0):

Lines, 2D, 3D graphics can be achieved in HTML5 using canvas. Refer [HTML5 canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

Comment: Without Canvas.